# Playing Background Music in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, playback

Ive tried previous question tutorials and still am not able to figure out how to play background music. I just want to play simple background music over loops. I've tried this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drums" ofType:@"mp3"];
  theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPathath] error:NULL];
  theAudio.delegate = self;
  theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
  [theAudio play];
```

I still can't get it to play. Ive also tried changing the background tasks of my info.plist to suit audio but couldn't find where to do that.

Comment: why is the number of loops -1?

Comment: So it repeats itself

Comment: Please, use the `error` parameter of `initWithContentsOfURL:error:` it may help you point out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add this key in your plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
          <string>audio</string>
  </array>
```

add some more line of code in your code

```
 theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

theAudio.delegate = self;
theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
[theAudio play];
```

This work for me.